# display image with strapi and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, strapi

I'm starting react with strapi and I can't display an image correctly.

My "animals" collection has an "image" field which is used to display an image.

However, I can't display the image (which is in upload)

In fact, I can't display the data that is in the image

Thanks to everyone who will help me

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'


function AnimauxListe() {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [Animaux, setAnimaux] = useState([]);
    const api_url = "http://localhost:1337/"
 
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get('http://localhost:1337/api/animaux?populate=*')
          .then(({ data }) => setAnimaux(data.data))
          .catch((error) => setError(error))
      }, [])
    
      if (error) {
        // Print errors if any
        return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
      }
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h2> Affichage des animaux présents dans la base de données</h2>
    <ul>
    {Animaux.map(animal =>
        <div key="animal.attributes.id" className="card" >  
        <img  src={animal.attributes.image.url}
          className="card-img-top" alt="raté"/>  
        <div className="card-body">  
        <h5 className="card-title">{animal.attributes.image.url}{animal.attributes.nom}</h5>
          <p className="card-text">{animal.attributes.Description}</p> 
          <p>{animal.attributes.image.url}</p>
           <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Voir {animal.attributes.nom}</a> 
            </div> </div>
    
    
    )}
    </ul>

    
  </div>
  )
}
```

On my code, I'm just trying to retrieve the url of the image for the moment but impossible. With all the updates I can't find a topic that matches my problem with a solution that fixes it.
thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0mjM.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this line

```js
const [Animaux, setAnimaux] = useState([]);
```

with this line

```js
const [animaux, setAnimaux] = useState([]);
...
{animaux.map(animal => return (
       <div key="animal.attributes.id" className="card" >  
           <img  src={animal.attributes.image.url} className="card-img-top" alt="raté"/>  
           <div className="card-body">  
               <h5 className="card-title">{animal.attributes.image.url {animal.attributes.nom}</h5>
               <p className="card-text">{animal.attributes.Description}</p> 
               <p>{animal.attributes.image.url}</p>
               <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Voir {animal.attributes.nom}</a> 
           </div>
       </div>
)}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer  !  I don't know Why but it's doesn't work :( I juste want to display my img

Comment: My img is in http://localhost:1337/api/upload/files so I do 

 <img  src={`http://localhost:1337/api/upload/files/${animal.id}`}

I am in the good location but i don't know how display my img

Comment: I think it's because Image is in other attributes ( see img in my post ) but I don't how go to this part

Comment: I tried too <img  src={`http://localhost:1337/uploads/${animal.attributes.image.hash}.jpg`} but same problem :/

Comment: The result in the image is stored in which variable?

Comment: I make the result directly in 
        <img  src={`http://localhost:1337/uploads/${animal.attributes.image.hash}.jpg`}
but I do 
       <h5 className="card-title">{animal.attributes.image.hash}{animal.attributes.nom}</h5> to see if y recup the result but anything is display

Comment: Try to replace 'animal.attributes' with 'animal.data[0].attributes' or 'animal.data[0]['attributes']

Comment: Really, thx u a lot for your time ! In this 2 cases I have AnimauxListe.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') error

Comment: Hmmm ok. Can you do a little 'console.log(animal)' inside the loop ? I need to see what this variable contains.

Comment: Again thx, 

https://puu.sh/J6cRL/d1ab67bdc7.png

I push an image because content was to long

Comment: Try 'animal.attributes.image.data[0]['attributes']['url']' or 'animal.attributes.image.data[0].attributes.url'

Comment: thx u a lot ! You are the best person in this worl !! ahah !